# Regular expression to validate hex string

Tags: .net, regex

I'm using this simple regular expression to validate a hex string:

```
^[A-Fa-f0-9]{16}$
```

As you can see, I'm using a quantifier to validate that the string is 16 characters long. I was wondering if I can use another quantifier in the same regex to validate the string length to be either 16 or 18 (not 17).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I believe

```
^([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){8,9}$
```

will work.

This is nice because it generalizes to any even-length string.

Comment: I agree, better: +1 (if Alonso wants to put the 'tick' solution mark on this answer rather than mine, I would understand ;) )

Comment: The inner expression could be optimized to ([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}), maybe even to ([[:xdigit:]]{2}) or (\p{XDigit}{2}). Depending on your regex flavor, pre-constructed character classes like the POSIX one perform better than hand-made ones.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, and I'm going to use it. But I don't understand it. Any chance someone can explain it? If hex characters can be 0-9 and A-F, I don't understand the breakdown of A-FA-f0-9. I thought a range would contain a lower and upper bound, like 0-9. How can there be four groups here? And what does A-FA mean? I know this works, I would just like to understand it.

Comment: There are three ranges in the [] clause: A-F matches uppercase letters, a-f matches lower case letters, and 0-9 matches digits.

Answer (score 9):

That's just a 16 character requirement with an optional 2 character afterwards:

```
^[A-Fa-f0-9]{16}([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})?$
```

The parentheses may not be required - I'm not enough of a regex guru to know offhand, I'm afraid. If anyone wants to edit it, do feel free...

Comment: From a performance point of view, this is *a lot* better. Much less backtracking on a non-match. +1

Comment: Parentheses are required here.  If you omit them, the ? makes the {2} lazy, which has no effect here.

Answer (score 5):

```
^(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{16}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{18})$
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with

```
/^[a-f0-9]{16}([a-f0-9]{2})?$/i
```

myself. I think it's more readable to set the regex as case insensitive and only list the character range once. That said, just about all of these answers work.

Comment: Like so many things, it's a tradeoff...  /[a-f]/i may be more readable (or may not, depending on the reader), but /[A-Fa-f]/ will run faster.  Probably not enough of a performance difference to be relevant in this case, though.