# How To validate UDH of SMS?

Tags: sms, gsm, smpp

we have a smpp server for sending sms. we can send UDH of each message if we want to use EMS or send Picture message , Ringtones or etc.
we have some users in our network so they can send to us sms message ( including UDH , Mclass and ... ). we want validate UDH of These messages before we send this messages to our smpp server.
i try many days to found guide about Validation of SMS UDH. ( UDH = User Data Header part of a sms packet )
i found some library written in java so that make UDH . but out problem is that we need to validate not build !
i need a library for UDH validation.
if that is not exist i want to know so how we can validate UDH ?

Comment: Hi Mehdi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is quite hard to understand (I realise that English is not your native language).  Do you want to validate the header of a message that is in SMPP format?

Comment: Dear S-list , sorry for poor english. i have a SOAP webservice for pushing sms from our users. then these message save in db and our smpp server send that message to sms provider. Our users can send UDH in a input parameter of SoAP request. format of sent UDH is Hex. I want Validate that UDH Hexstring. thank for ur attention

Comment: OK.  What sort of validation?  Are you looking for a regex to validate the length? (like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287684/regular-expression-to-validate-hex-string)    Or do you want to validate that all characters are hexadecimal?  Or something different?

Comment: no. i want validate so That UDH has Correct Structure and correct Format? for example if a user set udh , that udh must be a specific structure like UDH string for SMS to port , or send ringtone and other.. i want validate structure of udh.

Comment: You can write code to split the hex string into its separate fields.  For example, an int32 field would be 4 bytes.  Then check that each field contains a valid value.  If you need more help, then add a tag for the programming language that you are using to your question.